# Google Sheets Find Partial matches between two columns in multiple words strings in multiple orders

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am not a formula expert and am trying to achieve a specific thing on google sheets and I have tried the formulas already here and they don't seem to give me the result I need...

I basically analyse product data, and I pull list of products usually from two different sources. Then I manually compare them to find matches. This is very very tedious as you can imagine.

To give you an example I am currently comparing two price lists of hair products, and both contain many hundreds of products. I have to find the products that match up on both lists and then compare details etc.

I usually just pull the 'name' column from both sheets and put them into a new spreadsheet into columns A and B.

The problem is that we don't get UPC/EAN's on these lists and therefore need to compare the product names.

The product names on these lists are typically completely different, with all the words in different orders and very often have different words.. for example if the same product is found on both lists one entry can be 'Hair Volumising shiny Shampoo 30ml' and the other can be 'Rose Aoe Shampoo 30ml Volumising Hair' and they are the same product but the names are slightly different and the order is completely different.

I am looking for a formula that will do identify a  partial match in any order (eg here it would be 'volumising shampoo') and tell me where they are. 
This would need to be from one column to another eg from B to A - "**if there is anything in column 'a' that partially matches 'B' in any way in any order**", and then flag it.

If it could rate it somehow how much of a match it is ie maybe from 1-100 that would be ideal as it could then be sorted by this column.

Thanks so much for taking the time to read this

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE("♦"&ROW(A1:A)&" "&IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A, " "))<>"", LOWER(SPLIT(A1:A, " ")), )), 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(" ", 1, 
 LOWER(B1:B)), " ")), 1, 0))))),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), " "), 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1", 0),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]